# How to publish the entire publication?

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

After creating a new publication, what is the quickest way to publish everything? I tried right click on the publication and select "Publish", it failed in my setup. I am not sure whether it should work to start with.

Comment: Nuno describe the behavior but if you're seeing an actual error, it's typically a server limit. Share any errors from the publishing queue in that case to help pinpoint what needs to change on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Tridion will NOT publish new content when you publish an Organizational item (publications, structure groups).

There is a checkbox in the publishing dialog that changes this behavior, something along the lines of "also publish new content items" or similar.

This is done to prevent accidental publishing of new, not ready content by editors.

**edit**
New in this context means "content that has not been published to this target from this publication before".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Nuno has suggested, and if your Tridion System is properly maintained as per the SDL Tridion Maintenance Guide (In specific if the Indexes are maintained), then you may also make use of "Advanced Search" functionality to quickly publish everything.

For example: You may search for all pages with in the publication and publish all of them at once from the Search Result pane.

Alternatively, If you are using Dynamic Templates, you may search for all components with in the publication and publish them - this will publish all the Components based on the Dynamic Component templates as well as All the pages which are using those components.